# Тире или двоеточие после обобщающего слова? Как корректно?

Tags: пунктуация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как правильно?

1. Есть два глагола: *сидеть* и *седеть*, – имеющие разное значение, но пишущиеся почти по-одинаковому.
2. Есть два глагола: *сидеть* и *седеть* – имеющие разное значение, но пишущиеся почти по-одинаковому.
3. Есть два глагола – *сидеть* и *седеть*, – имеющие разное значение, но пишущиеся почти по-одинаковому.

Comment: Минусую за непонятность фразы.)

Comment: Убираю ваш минус:)   (Мне минусы не нравятся, они  негативные какие-то.)  Это омофоны.  При этом они пишутся по-разному и имеют разное значение. Что же непонятного?

Comment: @Sharon Да, омофоны, пусть, но не глаголы, точнее не потому что глаголы или два. Писать что это глаголы и продолжать про омофоны - это смысловая несогласованность. Поэтому и минусую до исправления или пояснения. О чём идет речь? - вот мой вопрос, но пояснения я не вижу. Но спасибо, что поддерживаете мой минус своим плюсом)

Comment: @Sharon Кстати, и в вашем ответе, также присутствует смысловая несогласованность. Так что вы попали в ловушку для котов. Это отвлекающий маневр. Вопрос же не в знаках препинания, знаки препинания для отвлечения от более серьёзных проблем с согласованием или смыслами.

Comment: Я думала об этом, сэр, но потом решила, что и так сойдет))  Насчет несогласованности там  все неоднозначно. А то еще будет разговоров на две недели.  А вопрос был о двоеточии и тире.

Comment: А как вам такая фраза: Есть два глагола: сидеть и седеть, которые имеют разное значение, но пишутся почти одинаково.  Здесь всего лишь причастный оборот заменен придаточным предложением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:

*Есть два глагола: **сидеть и седЕть**, // имеющие разное значение, но пишущиеся почти одинАково.*

**Пояснение**

(1) **Двоеточие** обозначает интонационное предупреждение (**какие именно**?).  Здесь достаточно запятой, в том числе по **произношению**.

(2) Не вижу причин  для постановки **тире** после  ***сидеть и седеть*** перед запятой, поставленной в соответствии со структурой предложения.

**Пример** (нет тире после однородного ряда):

*Он ... тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, продающиеся оптом, как то: **муку, пеньку, мед и прочее**, но покупает только небольшие безделушки...*

Comment: Но в РАН написано, что, когда есть перед перечислением двоеточие, нужно ставить тире, если что-то потом идёт.

Comment: А что именно потом идет?  Если запятая, то я тоже буду ставить тире. Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку.

Comment: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#

Comment: Там не рассматриваются сложные и осложненные предложения. Или приведите пример такой конструкции.

Comment: Что это значит – осложнённая?

Comment: Когда дальше идет обособленный оборот.

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103

Comment: I've found it! The 8th item! It says that the dash is optional!

Comment: I guess you should put both a dash and a comma if there are lots of things after the colon, whereas if that are a few, like in my example, a simple comma is enough.

Comment: Это § 36, примечания? Какое именно предложение?  Я не могу там ничего подобрать.  Тире может заменить двоеточие, но после ряда что именно идет?  I need a sample.

Comment: I have figured it out by myself. See the picture I've provided. In my case, I have to put a mere comma (without a dash), which was initially your suggestion.

Comment: Благодарю вас, сэр, но я все же укажу адрес.  Остается только разобраться в условиях контекста, чтобы каждый раз не списывать у Розенталя, а решать самим. Пожалуй, пора  это сделать.  https://evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm#з_07
§89. Обобщающие слова при однородных членах, пункт 3 (примечание).

Answer (score -1):

*Есть омонимы сидеть и седеть, имеющие разное значение, но пишущиеся почти одинаково.
Есть омонимы сидеть и седеть – имеющие разное значение, но пишущиеся почти одинаково.(если интонация требует тире)
Есть два омонима - сидеть и седеть, имеющие разное значение, но пишущиеся почти по-одинаковому.(не нужно дополнительных знаков, потому что они перегружают читабельность)
Есть два глагола - сидеть и седеть, имеющие разное значение, но пишущиеся почти одинаково.*

Скорее всего лучше поставить тире, потому что двоеточие подразумевает раскрытие прямого соответствия, и если два - то одно и другое в противопоставление, а тирешечка более свободный знак, её можно лепить куда угодно:

> В общем, есть два пути: Галилея и Джордано Бруно. (первый - второй - всё)

> Есть два рода бессмыслицы: одна происходит от недостатка чувств и мыслей, заменяемого словами; другая — от полноты чувств и мыслей и недостатка слов для их выражения. (два: один-; другой-)

Либо, если прямо хочется воткнуть двоеточие, то затем точку с запятой:

> У меня есть два приятеля: Степан Степанович Ладогин и Андрей Иванович Привольский; оба они люди умные, честные, добрые, живут очень дружно...

*Есть два глагола: сидеть и седеть; имеющие разное значение, но пишущиеся почти одинаково.*

Тире предполагает разорванные связи между частями, если будет тире между два глагола - имеющие разное значение, то наворочено. И еще, очевидно что глагола, тут неуместно. А если омонима между  "омонима и разное значение" не оправдано.

**Хотя тоже криво, просто фраза, как обычно, кривая и это, как обычно, попытка сделать фразу не кривой, через расстановку не менее кривой пунктуации.**

Об чём речь вообще? О глаголах или о схожем звучании-написании слов - омонимии? **Выбор слов не оправдан и не содержит четкости, и все начинает разваливаться.**

- Есть два слова: сидеть и седеть. Они имеют разное значение, но пишутся почти одинаково - это омонимы.
- Есть два глагола: сидеть и седеть; (продолжение, не связанное с предыдущим утверждением, выбор причастного оборота не оправдан) они имеют разное значение, но пишутся почти одинаково.

Есть два глагола, имеющие разное значение, но пишущиеся почти одинаково: сидеть и седеть. - ЗАЧЕМ? отрывать причастный оборот и соединять его через тире, при этом пытаясь составить грамотный текст?

Если это разговорный стиль, то тут вообще можно обойтись запятыми:

- **Есть два глагола, сидеть и седеть, имеющие разное значение, но пишущиеся почти по-одинаковому**.

Ни к чему не обязывающие утверждение, ничего не определяющая просто
болтовня, набор фраз разделенных акцентными запятыми. Дальше можно
хоть рожи добавить, хоть котиков, смысл от этого не исказится.

Говорить о сложной пунктуации есть смысл, когда фраза определена логически и семантически - без этого, можно хоть через запятые,
хоть через строфы делить фразы
хоть писать без заглавных букв
это никак не повлияет на информативность изложенного.

А вот-с - если понапихать сложной пунктуации.. добавить словечуечек и всякоих-такоих лишненьких выкрутасок; то это только увеличит степень нечитабельности фразы: пишите просто, - как классик завещал-таки.

**Текст должен быть читабельным и понятным - это основа.

Если текст нечитабельный и не понятный, то грамматикой это не исправить.**

Comment: Это от меня минус. Я вашу белиберду не читаю. Там кучу чего-то написано, и это никогда не по теме.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр  Смотри, котик, ты не указал, что не так-то. Вот у тебя есть ошибки намеренные и прочие в составлении фраз и понимании грамматики, я на них указываю конкретно,  что не так. А ты минусишь из личной неприязни, и скорее всего к себе.

Comment: Der Kater verstößt gegen diese Regeln, und er wird weiter dagegen verstoßen, weil ihm es egal ist. Sie sollten also nicht darauf achten.

Comment: Hören Sie bitte auf, die Fragen des Katers mit Ihren Korrekturen zu verschmutzen. Ich wäre Ihnen ziemlich dankbar.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр обязательно отвечу, когда выучу немецкий.